# How to run powershell cmdlets one after the other

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint 2010 list designed with custom solution. It has 3 level folder hierarchy. In the last folder level multiple documents are present as attachments. I want to get all the document attachments from that folder and store it in my local drive, so that it can be migrated to a different platform.
Number of Attachments are around 350000.

My Tasks are:

1. Creating Folder in my drive.
2. Getting Attachment ids and create folder with id name, as inputs from a txt file.
3. Map network drive
4. Copy attachment from network drive to local folder.
5. Delete network drive.

These 5 steps are to be repeated for around 350000 attachments.

Kindly let me know if cmdlets can be executed properly one after the other.

```
$idsFile = "H:\D\Temp\testingid.txt"
$FileStore = "H:\D\Temp\Attachments"

foreach ($line in Get-Content $idsFile) {
    $FileCount = 1

    $thisappid = $line.Split("`t")
    Write-Host $thisappid.GetValue(0)

    $FPath = $FileStore + '/' + $thisappid.GetValue(1)
    Write-Host $FPath
    if (!(Test-Path $FPath)) {
        Write-Host "Creating folder.."
        $F1 = New-Item -Path $FileStore -Name $thisappid.GetValue(1) -ItemType "directory"
        Write-Host $F1
        $F2 = New-Item -Path $F1 -Name $thisappid.GetValue(0) -ItemType "directory"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Folder" $thisappid.GetValue(1) "Already exists"
        $SPath = $FileStore + '/' + $thisappid.GetValue(1) + '/' + $thisappid.GetValue(0)
        Write-Host $SPath
        if (!(Test-Path $SPath)) {
            $F2 = New-Item -Path $SPath -Name $thisappid.GetValue(0) -ItemType "directory"
            Write-Host $F2
        } else {
            Write-Host "Folder" $thisappid.GetValue(0) "already exists"
            Write-Host "Move to Next.."
        }
    }

    Write-Host $thisappid.GetValue(0)
    $id = $thisappid.GetValue(0) -as [int]

    Write-Host $id
    Write-Host $id.GetType()
    net use Y: \\domainName/sites/SiteName/Lists/MyList/Attachments/$id
/Persistent:Yes
    Start-Sleep -s 10

    $name = Get-ChildItem -Path Y:\ -Name
    Start-Sleep -s 10

    Copy-Item -Path Y:\$name -Destination $dest
    Start-Sleep -s 10

    net use Y: /delete /y

    Start-Sleep -s 10

    $FileCount = $FileCount+1
    Write-Host $FileCount
}
```

Comment: PowerShell cmdlets and external commands will usually be run sequentially unless the command itself does some asynchronous operation, which AFAICS isn't the case here. Note, however, that mapping and removing shares is going to take some time, even if you removed all the 10s delays from your script. You may want to map the parent folder before the loop and remove it after the loop completes. Of course you need to adjust paths accordingly then. Note also, that the statement for mapping the network drives is wrapped incorrectly (`/Persistent:Yes` should be on the same line as `net use`).

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers